# I'm trying to draw text on my image but it's not showing up

Tags: python-2.7

I'm making a function that adds a border on a picture than applies text at a certain position but the text is not showing. I have the ttf font in my worker directory.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageOps, ImageFont

def framemaker1(original_image,percentwth,color,text,textcolor,textsize):
    img=Image.open(original_image)
    width,height=img.size
    thefont=ImageFont.truetype('BROADW.ttf',textsize)
    framewth=int(width*percentwth)
    framedimg=ImageOps.expand(img,border=framewth,fill=color)
    draw=ImageDraw.Draw(framedimg)
    draw.text=((framewth,height+framewth+0.25*framewth),text,thefont)
    framedimg.save('framed'+original_image)
    framedimg.show()
    print img.size
```

I wanted to have the text at the bottom right corner but no text appears.

Comment: The indentation of the line `def framemaker1(.....):` is wrong. Give it 4 backspaces.

Comment: I put it wrong in the post but the code does run, it's just that the text feature does not work